# Regex testers return results but not my site

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have used two testers of regex, http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm and http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/ both return the results I want but when ever I go 'Live' I get no results.

Heres the script I'm trying to get working:

```
$ptn = "/\\x(..)/";
$str = "\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53";
preg_match_all($ptn, $str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP converts your `$str` string into its actual characters, you are actually testing the string `"GLOBALS"`.

If you don't want escape sequences to be parsed, use single quotes:

```
$ptn = '/\\\x([0-9a-f]{2})/i';
$str = '\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53';
```